# Android: visibility:gone element is shortly visible

Tags: android, visibility, show-hide, floating-action-button

Hy,

I have the problem that a FloatingActionButton with visibility set to GONE shows up very short when opening the activity and then disappears as it should.

The button is used at a later point, that's why it must be invisible. At the moment though if somebody is fast enough (mainly on older devices/android versions), he can click the button before he should be allowed to.

My layout is pretty much the same as it was created by android studio, only that I set the visibility to gone:

```
<android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools" android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent" android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
tools:context="com.fallenritemonk.ludus.game.GameActivity">

<android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_width="match_parent" android:theme="@style/AppTheme.AppBarOverlay">

    <android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar android:id="@+id/toolbar"
        android:layout_width="match_parent" android:layout_height="?attr/actionBarSize"
        android:background="?attr/colorPrimary" app:popupTheme="@style/AppTheme.PopupOverlay" />

</android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout>

<include layout="@layout/content_game" />

<android.support.design.widget.FloatingActionButton
    android:id="@+id/add_fields_fab"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_gravity="bottom|end"
    android:layout_margin="@dimen/fab_margin"
    android:src="@drawable/ic_add"
    android:visibility="gone" />

</android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout>
```

content_game.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
app:layout_behavior="@string/appbar_scrolling_view_behavior"
tools:context="com.fallenritemonk.ludus.game.GameActivity">

<GridView
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:id="@+id/fieldGrid"
    android:numColumns="9"
    android:verticalSpacing="5dp"
    android:horizontalSpacing="5dp" />

</RelativeLayout>
```

I have no clue where the problem could be. I tried also setting it INVISIBLE instead of GONE. Since I cannot determine if the user was fast enough to press the button before he should have been able to, the only possibility to prevent him from doing so is to remove this "flashing up of the FAB"-bug.

If any more information needed feel free to ask!!!

Thanks for your help

Comment: when you are setting fab in to visible ?, this xml says fab will be GONE always

Comment: post related java code

Comment: The problem is not of setting the button visible at a later point, but that even if i don't set it visible, it still shows up very short at the launch of the activity.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem seems to have been solved by simply updating the android support design library. I now have updated it from 23.0.1 to 23.1.1!

Answer (score 0):

Try disabling the anchor id and after that set the visibility. It should work.

Try the following:

```
FloatingActionButton fab = (FloatingActionButton) findViewById(R.id.fab);
CoordinatorLayout.LayoutParams param = (CoordinatorLayout.LayoutParams) fab.getLayoutParams();
param.setBehavior(null);
param.setAnchorId(View.NO_ID);
fab.setLayoutParams(param);
fab.setVisibility(View.GONE);

// TO show again
param.setBehavior(new FloatingActionButton.Behavior());
param.setAnchorId(R.id.appbar);
fab.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
```

Comment: Nope, that doesn't work. The button is still shown for a short moment at launch of the activity!

Answer (score 0):

Just add fab.hide() to your onCreate() method (or onCreateView() if using Fragment). You can remove visibility tag from xml as it will no longer be needed. If you want to show your FAB, use fab.show();

Comment: Remove any setVisiblity() methods and also remove android:visibility="gone" from xml. I had the same problem in my project and it works with hide() / show() methods. Don't use setVisibility for FloatingActionButton.

Answer (score 0):

Have no reputation enough to comment, so I answer here
Try to place tag `android.support.design.widget.FloatingActionButton` before `include`. If it does not help, please, provide content of `content_game`

Comment: No difference! Added content_game.xml to my question